# I need help to write specific code using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write code something like this:

```
if ( [*distance between two objects*] = [*for example: 20px*] ) { 
[*run someFunction()*] 
}
```

I have written many different codes and logics , but it's little different for me...

I made mini game using js like a chrome dino game... the runner is approached by various obstacles that it must avoid , you can jump using space button but now I want to make auto jump function when an obstacle approaches him and there will be a specific distance between them I want it to be activated jump function...

*maybe I have to use the Pythagorean theorem, something like this?*

```
var a = x1 - x2;
var b = y1 - y2;
var c = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
// c is the distance

if(c == "20px" ) {
onJump(); 
};
```

But how can I practically use it?

Please help me if you can...

Comment: Yes, the distance formula is fine. What is the problem you have to make it work?

Comment: What HTML elements do you have? How are they positioned (is it hardcoded, computed by CSS or computed by JS)? The fact that you're not talking about point objects also complicates the calculations.

Comment: @Fzs I made mini game using js like a chrome dino game... the runner is approached by various obstacles that it must avoid , you can jump using space button but now I want to make auto jump function when an obstacle approaches him and there will be a specific distance between them I want it to be activated jump function...

Comment: `if (c > 20)`, `if (c === 20)` or `if (c >= 20)` depending on what you want the comparison to be. Greater than, equivalent to, or greater or equal than. Chances are, `if (c === 20)` is not going to useful since `c` will rarely be an integer unless you are using a pythagorean triplet.

Comment: P.s. Update your question to represent what you said in the comments. As currently your question is unclear. It looks like you're asking how to equate in an if statement.

Comment: @Wakka sorry sometimes I can't explain something in English... ok I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the distance you want to do something like this.

Just bare in mind because I;m using display inline block it add's a little extra margin between elements hence the extra bit of px.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var eleY = document.getElementById('y'),
    eleX = document.getElementById('x'),
    y = eleY.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    x = eleX.getBoundingClientRect().right,
    distance = y - x;

  eleY.innerHTML = 'y = ' + y;
  eleX.innerHTML = 'x = ' + x;
  document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = 'distance = ' + distance;
  
  if(distance == 138){
    alert('JUMP');
  }
  
}
```

```css
div {
  padding:35px 0;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}


#x {
  background: red;
}

#distance {
  width:100px;
  padding:10px 5px;
  color:#fff;
  background:green;
  margin:0 10px;
  
}

#y {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="x"></div>
  <div id="distance"></div>
  <div id="y"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I know this but I can't understand how to indicate distance between two html objects using "var c"

Comment: for example: I have two html elements ... I want to run some function when distance between this objects = 20px.

Comment: Are you talking about the physical distance in pixels between one html Dom element and another?

Comment: Do you mean you actually want to use JS to get the distance between one element and another?

Comment: yes , I made mini game using js like a chrome dino game... the runner is approached by various obstacles that it must avoid , you can jump using space button but know I want to make auto jump function when an obstacle approaches him and there will be a specific distance between them I want it to be activated jump function... P.S. sorry for bad English if I don't writing grammarly

Comment: OK I'll update @Balu

Comment: @Balu Thats it updated.

Comment: @Wakka Oh, thanks that's what I needed.

Comment: @Balu excellent, best accept it as the answer then.